# Display the url opened by selenium webdriver on a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

For instance I have the following code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
d = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
d.get('https://www.google.nl/')
```

I am running this code from wsl on a jupyter notebook.
It executes but I want to be able to show the url that is opened in a chrome web browser.
for example, if I run the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Data-Ingestion-Cell/codes/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.nl/')
driver.maximize_window()
```

locally on spyder, it opens a new google chrome window saying that chrome is controlled by automated test software. I want to do the same in jupyter notebook :

[image]

Comment: If you want to use a Jupyter cell as an interactive browser, I think you need to use some libraries (if exist); for example, there is `ipysheet` library to create an interactive sheet. How about just printing screenshots of the URL page as a Jupyter cell result?

Comment: @J.Choi I'm already using screenshots :'D I want to be able to display it...

Comment: What are your trials and errors?